# Putting pixels with PIL gives error

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Newbie here.
i tried to put some number of pixel with random RGB-colors (like adding noise):

```
from PIL import Image
import random
img=Image.open('pic.bmp')
randomenter=int(input('Enter numpix: '))
for numpix in range(0, randomenter):
    x=random.randint(0,int(img.size[0]))
    y=random.randint(0,int(img.size[1]))
    r=random.randint(0,255)
    g=random.randint(0,255)
    b=random.randint(0,255)
    img.putpixel((x,y),(r,g,b))
img.show()
```

with `randomenter=100` it works sometimes. with higher values it gets me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\study\7sem\GiMS\labs\1laba\123.py", line 11, in <module>
    img.putpixel((x,y),(r,g,b))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pillow-3.3.1-py3.4-win-amd64.egg\PIL\Image.py", line 1512, in putpixel
    return self.im.putpixel(xy, value)
IndexError: image index out of range
```

What am I doing wrong?
pic with `(800, 500)` values

Comment: `random.randint` includes endpoints. Upper bound for x and y should be `img.size[n]-1`.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How posted @ŁukaszRogalsk, it solves by editing `x` and `y` to `img.size[0]-1` and `img.size[1]-1`